# What is the best way to find directories that exactly match a string irrespective of the path?

Tags: command-line, find, directory

Suppose I have the directories:

```
/foo/
/A/B/C/foo/D/E/
/F/foo/G/H/foo/I/
```

How can get a result that lists all the directories whose basename exactly matches
a given string (for example `foo` in here)?

```
/foo/
/A/B/C/foo/
/F/foo/
/F/foo/G/H/foo/
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
$ find / -type d -name foo -print
```